# How can I convert a CSV download into an Excel template I have created?

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery, export-to-excel

I have built an Excel template with eight columns. All of the data is available from a third party site via a CSV download.

The download contains all of the data I need. However, there are 21 columns. A lot of duplicated and unnecessary data.

For a seamless import with the template, I'd like to column names to match up exactly what I have on the template. For example, I'd like "Company Owner" to be changed just to "Owner". I'd like "Company" changed to "Client".

Essentially I'd like Excel to fill out column "Client" by looking in the dataset for a column called "Company".

This will be being processed multiple times a week, or possibly daily. Of course I can do the task manually but if there's a quicker way to do this in Excel, that would be ideal.

Some Google searching led me to believing Power Query could achieve what I'm looking for.

I've "built" the template as a query, and imported the data set as another query.

I cannot work out how to essentially merge the two and ask the template to look in X column for the data, based on the name.

Comment: I'm not sure what a template is but you can get better help by editing your question to post a sample of your input data and a sample of your desired output format. Otherwise we have nothing to work with to help you

Comment: Power Query would be my suggestion as well, but it's hard to determine the best course of action without the information @horseyride recommends.  I'm not sure a 'merge' is the route to take, but use the CSV as the sole source and work that through to your desired end game in PowerQuery.  You may find it useful to tick "Preserve column sort/filter/layout" in the External Data Properties of the resulting table.